# Convert DateTime to date and then return only the date as string

Tags: c#

I am passing `"/Date(1541116800000)/"` as string in my method. How to extract only date and then return it as string in if condition?

```
public convertDateToString(string value)
{
   if (DateTime.TryParseExact("yyyy-MM-dd"), out string dateValue)
        return value; (returns just the date from datetime in string format)
}
```

Comment: Step one is to parse the string as `DateTime`. See marked duplicate. From that, it's a simple matter of then using `ToString()` on the resulting value with the appropriate format. See the hundreds of similar questions already on Stack Overflow for more details about that.

Answer (score 2):

It's a Javascript date. If you have a Json library like [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/), try this:

```
public string convertDateToString(string value)
{
    var dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>($"\"{value}\"");
    return dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
}
```

Usage

```
convertDateToString("/Date(1541116800000)/")
```

Output

```
2018-11-02
```

Comment: It should accept any form of datetime and return only the date part in string format.

Comment: @Eva would the updated work for you?